# Jquery autocomplete : How to prevent duplicate on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent duplicate selection in `select: function()` if a specific id is previously selected.
I want to prevent `roll No` duplicate in my code as following.

```
    select: function( event, ui ) { 
            //var item = ui.item.data;                      
        id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id_arr.split("_");            
        $('#rollNumber_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.rollNumber);
        $('#name_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.name);  
        $('#class_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.class);  
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="students">
  <div id="first">
   <input type="number" id="rollNumber_1" >
   <input type="text" class="name" id="name_1" >
   <input type="text" id="class_1" >
  </div>
  <div id="second">
   <input type="number" id="rollNumber_2" >
   <input type="text" class="name" id="name_2" >
   <input type="text" id="class_2" >
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: please share your html too

Comment: @Shubh question is updated with HTML

Comment: What exactly your are looking?,where you are calling your select function?

Comment: @Shubh inside autocomplete with ajax function.

Comment: @Shubh on selection if selected data have the same roll no as before selected then it should prevent selection and show a message of duplicate in alert box.

Comment: @Dishko Can you please create a JS Fiddle for the code? Your question is not clear enough to provide you the solution. Please try to share Fiddle.

Comment: @KrunalPanchal [code](https://pastebin.com/MrWYbz8v).

Comment: To prevent duplicate selection, you need to save the reference of Previously selected ids. You just want to prevent duplicate selection that's it? How are you adding <input type="number" id="rollNumber_2" > in HTML? using js?

Comment: @Dishko I posted my answer with 2 approaches you can try. Check and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To prevent Duplication**

There can be many different approaches, It depends on Code logic and situation. From the current Situation and code, I see 2 ways to do it.

1. As you are setting the value of $('#rollNumber_'+id[1]), You can validate if Value is empty or not. If it's empty means, User is selecting it for the first time. :D
2. Saving selected Ids in an Array or Dom.

**Let me give a sample demo**

**Approach 1**

```
select: function( event, ui ) {                       
    id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");  

    /* Logic goes here */
    var rollNoVal = $('#rollNumber_'+id[1]).val();

    if(rollNoVal != '') {
       console.log('Duplicate selection is not allowed');
       return;
    }
    /* Logic done here */

    $('#rollNumber_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.rollNumber);
    $('#name_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.name);  
    $('#class_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.class);  
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
  var selectedStudents = [];
  select: function( event, ui ) {                       
    id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");  

    /* Logic goes here */
    var inArrayExists = selectedStudents.indexOf(ui.item.data.rollNumber);
    if(inArrayExists != -1) {
       console.log('Duplicate selection is not allowed');
       return;
    }

    // Push to an array
    selectedStudents.push(ui.item.data.rollNumber);
    /* Logic done here */

    $('#rollNumber_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.rollNumber);
    $('#name_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.name);  
    $('#class_'+id[1]).val(ui.item.data.class);  
 }
```

Comment: Approach worked for me thank you, Approach 1 not doing any thing.

Comment: @Dishko It depends on a real scenario. :) Anyway, Happy that it helped.